# Encoding error "entity not defined" in XML RSS feed with PHP MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, xml, character-encoding, rss

I am trying to develop my own XML RSS feed based on PHP output from MySQL queries. However I keep getting "entity X not defined" error messages for all the ASCII characters in my DB content fields, even though I have set everything to UTF8 encoding and charset (database connection, xml version, utf8_encode), but nothing removes the error:

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect( .... )
$connection->set_charset("utf8");
header("Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
echo '<rss version="2.0">';
$query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY pubdate DESC LIMIT 10");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
$title = utf8_encode($row['title']);
$content = utf8_encode($row['content']);
echo '<item><title>'.$title.'</title>';
echo '<description>'.$content.'</description></item>';
} // end while
echo '</channel>';
echo '</rss>';
?>
```

What am I missing?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please include the generated XML code (or a sufficiently long extract thereof) in the question.

Comment: The problem you have is that you create the XML by hand instead of using a library that has been created for creating XML, like in your case for example SimpleXML or DOMDocument. Those libraries take care of the proper XML encoding of UTF-8 encoded strings you get from your database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also faced the same issue and fixed using below link

I think you are looking for this

http://help.simplytestable.com/errors/html-validation/general-entity-x-not-defined-and-no-default-entity/

Comment: I'm the author of the above-linked help article. Good to see it coming in useful!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to escape the `$title` and `$content` variables. Check [htmlspecialchars()](http://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars).

For a better solution, use [DOM](http://www.php.net/dom) to create the the XML. This will make sure that you create a valid XML.